# Msys2 -> f951.exe: Fatal Error: Reading module '...' at line 2 column 1: Unexpected EOF

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran, msys2

I am trying to use a module with **gfortran 8.2.0 under Win 10 + Portable Msys2**.
This problem does not show up with **gfortran 7.3.0 under Ubuntu 18.04LTS**.
After failing to compile my actual case, I put together

**My [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) or [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**:

- `main.f90`:

  ```
  program main_prog
  use testmod
  implicit none
  integer :: j
  end program main_prog
  ```
- `mod_testmod.f90`:

  ```
  module testmod
  implicit none
  <various statements>
  end module testmod
  ```

  depending on the contents of `<various statements>`, compilation worked or failed (see below).

**Compilation**

- `mod_testmod.f90`: Compiled ok, regardless of the combinations that I used for `<various statements>` (`mod_testmod.o` and `testmod.mod` were created with no errors):

  ```
  $ gfortran -g -c -o mod_testmod.o mod_testmod.f90
  ```
- `main.f90`: 
  `<various statements>` (in `mod_testmod.f90`!) consisted of a few variable definitions:

  ```
  integer :: Npuntos=10             ! def 1
  double precision :: PI=3.1415296  ! def 2
  double precision :: T=4.0         ! def 3
  double precision :: T0=4.0        ! def 4
  double precision :: S0=4.0        ! def 5
  ```

  which were commented/uncommented. Depending on the combination, compilation worked or failed (it completely puzzles me, all should work).
  When failed, the error message was

  ```
  $ gfortran -g -c -o main.o main.f90
  f951.exe: Fatal Error: Reading module 'testmod' at line 34 column 62: Unexpected EOF
  compilation terminated.
  ```

  I wouldn't know if the line/column combination is of any use to track the problem.

  Combinations of unocmmented definitions that worked:
  (1), 
  (1,4,5), 
  (2,4,5), 
  (3,4,5), 
  (1,2,3,4), 
  (1,2,4,5),

  Combinations of unocmmented definitions that failed:
  (none) (comment by High Performance Mark was right), 
  (4,5), 
  (1,3,4,5), 
  (1,2,3,4,5),

  These are the combinations I tried, enough to have me completely lost on what's going on.

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: Can you show what is inside `testmod.mod`? Unfortunately, they moved to a binary format for the .mod files.

Comment: Can you delete all object files and module files --- to make sure everything is clean and produced by the current version of the compiler --- and reissue `gfortran.exe -c mod_testmod.f90` and `gfortran.exe -c main.f90`?

Comment: @VladimirF - You are seeing what I have. It is an empty module, put together as a MCVE.
Please see updated OP.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl - This is what I did. It is a MCVE put together from scratch.

Comment: @sancho.s I was requesting the file `testmod.mod`, I say again `.MOD`. That is not the file you show but it is the file the compiler is complaining about. Try to delete it now, even if you started from scratch.

Comment: @VladimirF - My apologies... Should I place it online and post the link?
Please see updated OP, with further things I tried.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - You were right. That was only one form of the problem. But it still persists, see updated OP.

Comment: The file is probably not important now that we have more information.

Comment: @VladimirF - The problem seems to be specific to Msys2+gfortran, see updated OP.

Comment: Hmm from the sound of the message I wonder if the core of the problem is not in the unix/windows end lines.  Could you please check all your files if you have the correct line ends?

Comment: @tukan - That is likely not the problem. 1) I checked CR/LF for all lines. 2) If that were the case, there would not be *combinations of lines* that fail, but only *lines* that fail. Note that each of the 5 lines takes part of at least one combination that works, so they should all work, if the issue were CR/LFs.

Comment: @sancho.s Ah, did not take the *combination of lines that fail* into account.  You are right that has to something fishy with the fortran itself.  I'll try to reproduce it today to check if I can help you.

Comment: @tukan - Also note that the error states Error: Reading module 'testmod' at line 34 column 62... Why would it refer to module testmod (instead of file mod_testmod.f90), and why would it refer to line 34(the source file has only 9 lines).

Comment: Hard to say.  Maybe some path issue?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio did you ever manage to solve this? We see at least a similar problem (on one machine only, msys/mingw/gcc updated), and I'm at the end of things to try.

Comment: @Christoph - I am not using this since a long time ago. I don't remember if I ever solved this, although I suspect I didn't; otherwise I would have probably posted my solution.

Comment: I understand, thanks anyway, [DenverCoder9](https://xkcd.com/979/) :-P ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend upgrading your msys2 installation.  I have tried your MCVE on my  `gfortran 8.3.0-2` (`mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libgfortran 8.3.0-2 (mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain)`) and **windows 7** (I don't have a virtual machine with win10 yet) with **msys2**.

I updated my msys2 installation with `pacman -Syu`.  Next I searched for gfortran via `pacman -Ss gfortran` and picked the x64 version.

To check I had the fortran:

```
$ whereis gfortran
gfortran: /mingw64/bin/gfortran.exe
```

I did this:

`main.f90`:

```
module testmod
implicit none
integer :: Npuntos=10             ! def 1
double precision :: PI=3.1415296  ! def 2
double precision :: T=4.0         ! def 3
double precision :: T0=4.0        ! def 4
double precision :: S0=4.0        ! def 5
end module testmod
```

and

`mod_testmod.f90`:

```
program main_prog
use testmod
implicit none
integer :: j
end program main_prog
```

Here is the log:

```
Ugun@thor MSYS /c/t/fortran
$ gfortran -g -c -o mod_testmod.o mod_testmod.f90

Ugun@thor MSYS /c/t/fortran
$ ls
main.f90  mod_testmod.f90  mod_testmod.o  testmod.mod

Ugun@thor MSYS /c/t/fortran
$ gfortran -g -c -o main.o main.f90
```

**Note:** for the sake of completness I have tried all the combinations you reported as failed and all were successful.

1. I think you should upgrade your **MSYS2** env.
2. Upgrade your gfortran installation.

Comment: I will try this and post back. Did you also try some failing combinations *before* upgrading msys2/gfortran?

Comment: @sancho.s I did not have the old installed gfortran so I did not test it.  I have installed `gfortran` (which happened to be newer) that just to test your case.

Comment: I am having difficulties in upgrading... I find it weird that the upgrade may solve the issue, but I will keep trying.

Comment: @sancho.s maybe you could try whole new MSYS2 env.  It maybe a bug somewhere and it was fixed in the upgrade.  I don't find it that strange.  There are bugs everywhere.

Comment: I have just upgraded to 8.3.0, and I get the same error.

Comment: @sancho.s That is weird.  Can you try it on fresh install?  My guess is that you have something wrong in your environment.

Comment: I can. Though it will take me some time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this problem is caused by the search rule of msys2. This error will emerge as long as there exists any invalid path before the location of `msys64\mingw64\bin` in `path` of `Environment Variables`.

You can solve this problem either by removing those invalid paths or moving the mingw64 path location to the first one.